# airflow operator import doesn't seem to work

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow and need some direction on this one...
I'm creating my first dag that uses a subdag and importing the subdag operator

```
`from airflow.operators.subdag import SubDagOperator`
```

however I keep getting the flowing error
"Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/POC_Main_DAG.py] No module named 'airflow.operators.subdag'"

I also tried importing the dummy operator ang got the same error.
on the other hand the below operators seem to be imported as expected.

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator
```

appreciate help on resolving this issue
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What version of Airflow are you using?

If you are using Airflow 1.10.x, use the following:

```py
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
```

In Airflow >=2.0.0, use the following:

```py
from airflow.operators.subdag import SubDagOperator

from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Version : 1.10.4. i changed the code in the way you suggested and now it works.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use :-
pip install apache-airflow=1.10.15
or
pip install apache-airflow=1.10.X